# Ambiguous use of operator<< inside my class

Tags: c++

I have a problem with creating an operator<< in a class in this particular situation. I have a class that wraps a std::ostream so I can do some preprocessing for some types or some conditions before passing to the ostream, and want to pass some things straight through. I don't want to inherit the std::ostream, unless there is a good argument that I should. (I think I tried it once and found great difficulty and no success.)

I cannot use a template function because the processing depends on type in some cases, and I think the ambiguity would remain between it and those for my specific types (like 'Stuff'). Do I have to resort to using typeid ??

```
class MyClass
{
  private:
    std::ostream & m_out;

  public:
    MyClass (std::ostream & out)
      : m_out(out)
    {}

    MyClass & operator<< (const Stuff & stuff)
    {
        //...
        // something derived from processing stuff, unknown to stuff
        m_out << something;
        return *this;
    }

    // if I explicitly create operator<< for char, int, and double, 
    // such as shown for char and int below, I get a compile error: 
    // ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' on later attempt to use them.

    MyClass & operator<< (char c)
    {
        m_out << c; // needs to be as a char
        return *this;
    }

    MyClass & operator<< (int i)
    {
        if (/* some condition */)
            i *= 3;
        m_out << i; // needs to be as an integer
        return *this;
    }

    // ...and other overloads that do not create an ambiguity issue...
    // MyClass & operator<< (const std::string & str)
    // MyClass & operator<< (const char * str)        
};

void doSomething ()
{
    MyClass proc(std::cout);
    Stuff s1, s2;
    unsigned i = 1;
    proc << s1 << "using stuff and strings is fine" << s2;
    proc << i; // compile error here: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' in 'proc << i'
}
```

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  Perhaps you'd be better off implementing a `std::streambuf` or some other layer of the C++ I/O system rather than an entire stream?

Comment: I just realized the problem. The integer in doSomething() is unsigned and there is no operator<< (unsigned). Of course since there was no exact match, the compiler doesn't know which to use... I was hoping I did not have to overide all signed/unsigned type variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the value you're trying to insert is `unsigned` while the overloads you've provided only work on signed types. As far as the compiler is concerned, converting unsigned to `int` or `char` are both equally good/bad and result in ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use a template function because the processing depends on type in some cases

Just make overloadings for those types.

> I think the ambiguity would remain between it and those for my specific types (like 'Stuff').

No. If `operator<<` is overloaded for specific type, this overloading will be called. Otherwise will be called template function.

```
template <class T>
MyClass& operator<< (const T& t)
{
    m_out << t;
    return *this;
}
```